# How do I change flutter app icon background color?

Tags: flutter

Right now it's black, but I want white. Thanks for your help ^ v ^

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's an icon made by you not flutter.So you have to manually change the background colour with whichever tool you've used to design it.e.g : photoshop ,Sketch